# Does designating a foreign key automatically take care of updates to the foreign table's value?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have two tables: `student` and `faculty`

I added a column to the `student` table that is a foreign key that references a column in `faculty`.

Let's say that a faculty's id ***changes***. Based on my code below, will my `student` table update accordingly? Or do I need to do anything extra to ensure that it updates? For example, pretend that James's id updates from 1 to 99. Will the advisorid column of `student` update accordingly?

Note - I am using LINQPad and I have no way to test this because when I try to make a change to the referenced table I get an `Error 547: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__enroll__studenti__178D7CA5". The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.enroll", column 'studentid'`.

```
alter table student
add advisorid int foreign key(advisorid) references faculty(facultyid);

update student set advisorid = 1 where studentid = 1;

select * from student

select * from faculty;
```

[image]

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  some are more capable here than others. 
 Second bit...ID changing is bad practice...ID that are foriegn keys should never change.  The name of that faculty can change, a random ID stored as a data column that people refer to it as may change, but the FK ID should not.  (sad side note, but even in text examples, it appears females always make less)

Comment: Your second bit only completely applies to surrogate keys @Twelfth. It's _sometimes_ necessary to update a natural key, though it certainly shouldn't be a regular occurrence.

Comment: @Ben - agreed, but they don't look like natural keys here.

Comment: @Twelfth Oracle

Comment: Updated the tags. PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language; this is nothing to do with PL/SQL and is just SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the foreign keys automatically get updated as primary table is updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609649/does-the-foreign-keys-automatically-get-updated-as-primary-table-is-updated)

Comment: Please before you ask google & read the official manual for your dbms. This is a faq. Eg google your title witih 'sql oracle stackoverflow'. Also please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

As you've seen, by default, updates on the key a foreign key is based of do no propagate to the dependent columns. You can get such a behavior by specifying an `on update` clause:

```
alter table student
add advisorid int foreign key(advisorid) references faculty(facultyid)
on update cascade;
```

**EDIT:**
To answer the question in the comments, the behavior could also be defined when deleting a row:

```
alter table student
add advisorid int foreign key(advisorid) references faculty(facultyid)
on delete cascade
on update cascade;
```

Comment: Would the syntax for both updates and deletions be: `alter table student
add advisorid int foreign key(advisorid) references faculty(facultyid)
on update cascade on delete cascade;` ??

Comment: @JohnSmithy1266 yup, exactly.

Comment: It's worth noting @John that if you use `on update` you should _really_ create an index on the non-referenced column (in this case `advisorid`) to prevent full table scans for every update/delete. Depending on your RDBMS I'd recommend an index whether you're using the `on` clause or not to prevent blocking writes.

Comment: Sorry!! By force of habit I selected SQL Server as the tag but in reality this is a question about Oracle/PL-SQL, which I am learning! Sorry about that.

Comment: So Oracle doesn't have `ON UPDATE/DELETE CASCADE` it seems

Comment: `ON DELETE CASCADE` works in oracle `ON UPDATE CASCADE` does not

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle `ON UPDATE CASCADE` does not work. Here I will demonstrate an alternative update scenario.
Instead of specifying ON UPDATE CASCADE it is possible to deferring the check of a contraint to the end of a transaction. Therefore the constraint must be DEFERRABLE. Unfortuantely the constraint could not be modified so that it must dropped and recreated.

Here is an Example:

```
CREATE TABLE parent_ (
   pid NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_parent PRIMARY KEY,
   c1  VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE child_ (
   cid NUMBER,
   pid NUMBER CONSTRAINT fk_child_parent REFERENCES parent_(pid) ON DELETE CASCADE, --DEFERRABLE,
   c1  VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO parent_ VALUES (1, 'two');
INSERT INTO child_ VALUES (2, 1, 'two');

COMMIT;
```

An update of the primary key or foreign key will lead to an oracle exception

```
UPDATE parent_ SET pid = 2
Fehlerbericht -
SQL-Fehler: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (ME.FK_CHILD_PARENT) violated - child record found
02292. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - child record found"
*Cause:    attempted to delete a parent key value that had a foreign
           dependency.
*Action:   delete dependencies first then parent or disable constraint.

UPDATE child_ SET pid = 2
Fehlerbericht -
SQL-Fehler: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ME.FK_CHILD_PARENT) violated - parent key not found
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
*Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
*Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.
```

Now the foreign key will be re-created as deferrable. It will still lead to foreign key constraint violations but it can be set to deferred per session. The advantage is that all other session still behave as before.

```
ALTER TABLE child_ DROP CONSTRAINT fk_child_parent;
ALTER TABLE child_ ADD CONSTRAINT fk_child_parent FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES parent_(pid) ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE;

ALTER SESSION SET CONSTRAINTS = DEFERRED;

UPDATE parent_ SET pid = 2;
UPDATE child_ SET pid = 2;

COMMIT;

ALTER SESSION SET CONSTRAINTS = IMMEDIATE;
```

The DEFERRABLE attribute can also be set when creating a foreign key (also inline). Find more on that in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm)